# How do you create pretty json in CHEF (ruby)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, erb

How would you make an erb template that has human readable json?

The following code works, but it makes a flat json file

default.rb

```
default['foo']['bar'] = { :herp => 'true', :derp => 42 }
```

recipe.rb

```
template "foo.json" do
  source 'foo.json.erb'
  variables :settings => node['foo']['bar'].to_json
  action :create
end
```

foo.json.erb

```
<%= @settings %>
```

Similar SO questions
[Chef and ruby templates - how to loop though key value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11490781/chef-and-ruby-templates-hw-to-loop-though-key-value-pairs)
[How can I "pretty" format my JSON output in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86653/how-can-i-pretty-format-my-json-output-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: If your erb is just a single `<%= @something %>` you'd be better off using the [file resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_file.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172632/1626687) .erb templates are great for HTML, and XML, but is not good for json.

Luckily, CHEF uses its [own json library](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/json_compat.rb#L111) which has support for this using `.to_json_pretty`

@coderanger in IRC, pointed out that you can use this library right inside the recipe. [This article shows more extensively](https://www.chef.io/blog/2014/03/12/writing-libraries-in-chef-cookbooks/) how to use chef helpers in recipes.

default.rb

```
# if ['foo']['bar'] is null, to_json_pretty() will error
default['foo']['bar'] = {}
```

recipe/foo.rb

```
pretty_settings = Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(node['foo']['bar'])

template "foo.json" do
  source 'foo.json.erb'
  variables :settings => pretty_settings
  action :create
end
```

---

Or more concise as pointed out by YMMV

default.rb

```
# if ['foo']['bar'] is null, to_json_pretty() will error
default['foo']['bar'] = {}
```

recipe/foo.rb

```
template "foo.json" do
  source 'foo.json.erb'
  variables :settings => node['foo']['bar']
  action :create
end
```

templates/foo.json.erb

```
<%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@settings) %>
```

Comment: You should also be able to do this in your erb template:  <%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@settings) %>.  I kind of like that because it turns the responsibility of the format of the string into the view logic in the template.  YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this would also work:

```
file "/var/my-file.json" do
  content Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(node['foo']['bar'].to_hash)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= Chef::JSONCompat.to_json_pretty(@settings) %>` Works like Charm !!